# Many Gnome 3.28 daemons are using over 100 GB of VIRT. Why?

Tags: gnome, memory, gnome3, virtual-memory

I recently updated this laptop to Fedora 28 Beta and with it Gnome 3.28. Things are mostly good.

But some things are weird. This is not causing problems because this is all virtual memory.

But why are these daemons allocating 100+ GB of virtual memory?

```
0  1000  2012  1719  20   0 101649024 32904 SyS_po Sl ?         0:00 /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
0  1000  1983  1719  20   0 101704260 46416 SyS_po Sl ?         0:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server
0  1000  2210  1765  20   0 101736292 33656 SyS_po Sl+ tty2     0:00 /usr/libexec/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
0  1000  2452  1719  20   0 101927808 45988 SyS_po Ssl ?        0:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-addressbook-factory
0  1000  2240  1765  20   0 102007840 57328 SyS_po Sl+ tty2     0:00 /usr/libexec/evolution/evolution-alarm-notify
0  1000  2415  2288  20   0 102356528 47216 SyS_po Sl ?         0:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess --factory all --bus-name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx2288x2 --own-path /org/gnome/evolution/dataserver/Subprocess/Backend/Calendar/2288/2
0  1000  2021  1719  20   0 102405692 46532 SyS_po Ssl ?        0:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-source-registry
0  1000  2288  1719  20   0 118711416 46164 SyS_po Ssl ?        0:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory
0  1000  2518  2452  20   0 119163652 49648 SyS_po Sl ?         0:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-addressbook-factory-subprocess --factory all --bus-name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.AddressBookx2452x2 --own-path /org/gnome/evolution/dataserver/Subprocess/Backend/AddressBook/2452/2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of these daemons use WebKit (mostly to show oauth2 login prompts), and WebKit recently introduced gigacages to isolate the heap used by their JS implementation. The allocation for a gigacage is big enough that any access to an arbitrary unsigned 32 bit offset would still land in the gigacage, resulting in these huge allocations. See this blog post for more details on gigacages: https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/some-brief-notes-on-webkit-heap-hardening/